# Cannot set property 'eventCalendar' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm having this error 
Cannot set property 'eventCalendar' of undefined 
I put the script on the `</body>` on joomla

```
   $.fn.eventCalendar = function(options){
    var eventsOpts = $.extend({}, $.eventCalendar.defaults, options);

    // define global vars for the function
    var flags = {
        wrap: "",
        directionLeftMove: "300",
        eventsJson: {}
    }
};
```

Comment: that absolutely  means `$.fn` is not defined, now you should tell what is `$`?

Comment: like $.fn.eventCalendar = function(options) after the jquery already loads.